# How to center content vertically with unknown content and fixed layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a simple layout of header, footer and content between, where each such section has **unknown height** (content). Target is to have header up, footer down and content centered in between, showing vertical scroll-bar only when it is needed. I was able to take care of header, footer and scroll-bar by code listed below, but I cannot find a way how to center content in between.

Here is a fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/mVh44/**

---

#### >> HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="headerText">
      header header header
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
      center text here
  </div>
  <div id="footerPadding">
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div id="footerText">
      footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer 
      footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### >> CSS:

```
html, body {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: .9em;
    color: black;
    height: 100%; /* needed for container min-height */
}

div {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

div#container {
    position: relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
    margin: 0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height: 100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/
    min-height: 100%; /* real browsers */
}

div#header, div#footer {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

div#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* stick to bottom */
}

div#headerText, div#footerText {
    padding: 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div#headerText {
    border-bottom: .5em double gray;
}

div#footerText {
    border-top: .5em double gray;
}
```

#### >> Script:

```
function myResize() {
  $('#footerPadding'  ).css('height', $('#footer').css('height'));
}

$(window).resize(function(){
  myResize()
});

myResize();
```

Comment: Why don't you add the footer and the header as fixed elements?

Comment: @Alvaro - to allow scroll when it is needed

Comment: But do you only want the scroll in the middle section?

Comment: @Alvaro - no, the entire page/document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS and changing your HTML markup.

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/mVh44/12/

**CSS**

---

```
#header{
    position:absolute;    
    top:0;
}
div#footer{
    position:relative;
    display:table-row;
}
#container{
    padding:  48px 0 0 0; //48px from the header 
    display:table;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
         box-sizing: border-box; 
}
#content{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

---

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerText">header header header</div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="box">center text here</div>
        <div class="box">center text here</div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footerText">footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

---

```
function myResize() {
    var headerHeight = $('#header').height();
    var windowsWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#footerPadding').css('height', $('#footer').css('height'));
    $('#container').css('padding-top', headerHeight + 'px');
    $('#footerText').css('width', windowsWidth + 'px');
}
```

Comment: Well, your `48px` comes from where? Content will be unknown, so its height. Besides of this major point, test your fiddle and resize it to minimum height to see that it does not work anyway...

Comment: Why dosn't it work at the min height?  I see a scrollbar and it all scrolls...  Please elaborate on what you actually want to happen.

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ i commented it in here... From the header and footer.

Comment: Header and footer have unknown content, so their height is unknown. Your `48px` fits for the content in the example, but when such content of header or footer will change (dynamically), your code/solution would not work.

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ you forgot to mention that. But anyway, then just make use of jQuery to get the new height and apply it to the `#container` element with `$.css`. Make use of the `resize` event of jQuery to trigger your code.

Comment: Really? Forgot? Sure not. Read question - it says **"where each such section has unknown height"**

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ well, just follow what I told you in my last comment. If you have troubles just let me know.

Comment: Test your recent fiddle(s) and you see that your solution added horizontal scroll-bar, that should never pop-up!

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer with the needed jQuery. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: In Chrome it seems to work fine.  Unless I still don't know what @ΩmegaΔ is asking for.

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ is talking about the scroll bar added by **jsfiddle** as the content in your footer is very big and has the style `white-space: nowrap;`. Just delete that :)

Comment: I cannot delete it, because I need it there!!! I have there also `overflow: hidden;` to ensure horizontal scroll-bar will not pop-up, so `white-space: nowrap;` cannot be an issue then! See my original fiddle - test it - no horizontal scroll-bar! Got it?

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ get calm dude! Take a tea or something! hahaha :) Just add a bit more o jQuery magic then, life is beautiful dude! I updated my answer. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mVh44/12/

Comment: Dude, right? Hmmm. Okay dog, listen - your most recent (12) solution seems okay now. I will check it later, maybe some other solution will show up, so I will do final testing afternoon. But you tried hard. Thanks. I was calm, very calm, but I don't like fast work, when people don't read entire question, then don't check their own solution and act in hurry - just like you did. :) Anyway, thanks and +1 for now...